# How to delete a file from a library without deleting the recycled version programatically in MOSS2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am facing an issue where-in SPFile.Delete() is deleting all my versions of the file even from the recycle bin. I do not want the file version which is there in the Recycle Bin to be deleted.

For Example : I have created 4 versions of the same file xyz.xls. Now I delete the 2nd version of the file from the UI. This send my 2nd version to the Recycle Bin. Now what I need is that when I call SPFile.Delete(), it should delete the 4 other versions of the file and not the one that is in the recycle bin. Currently it is deleting the version in the recycle bin also.

What I have to achieve is that the version of the file which is present in the Recycle Bin should not get deleted. Only the versions present in the library should get deleted when I call SPFile.Delete().

The solution mentioned at some places to use .Recycle() will just move all the versions to the recycle bin. But what I need is that the versions of the file that are present in the library should permanentlly get deleted whereas the version of the file present in the Recycle Bin should not get deleted at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through file's versions and delete them one by one. It will probably be slower but I think it will achieve what you are looking for

```
foreach(SPFileVersion version in file.Versions)
{
    version.Delete()
}
```

This way you will delete only version that are currently in the file and not in the Recycle Bin.